# rostopic for Kinect

Tags: ros, kinect, image-raw, image

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Which is the exact rostopic for Kinect raw image viewer.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/40849/rostopic-for-kinect/) by [Arjun PE](https://answers.ros.org/users/2019/arjun-pe/) on ROS Answers with karma: 18 on 2012-08-08

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) on 2012-08-08**:
Please provide more information. Which ROS version are you using? How do you start the kinect node, i.e. which launch file are you using? Make sure you have a look at the guidelines: http://www.ros.org/wiki/Support

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

got it... its /camera/rgb/image_raw

---

Originally posted by [Arjun PE](https://answers.ros.org/users/2019/arjun-pe/) with karma: 18 on 2012-08-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0